# Android scrollview scrolls more than needed

Tags: java, android, view, scrollview

I added scrollview to a relative layout, but it scrolls more than I needed. If I remove the scrollview, it will not show the last two buttonImages. So I added srollview.

[image]

[image]

Here is the code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true" >  


<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background_image"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
    android:src="@drawable/logo" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="92dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_layout"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="25dp"
    android:text="Team Bio"
    android:textColor="#F8F8FF"
    android:textSize="30dp" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_layout"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="25dp"
    android:text="Contact Us"
    android:textColor="#F8F8FF"
    android:textSize="30dp" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_layout"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="25dp"
    android:text="Facebook"
    android:textColor="#F8F8FF"
    android:textSize="30dp" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_layout"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="25dp"
    android:text="Twitter"
    android:textColor="#F8F8FF"
    android:textSize="30dp" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_layout"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="25dp"
    android:text="Youtube"
    android:textColor="#F8F8FF"
    android:textSize="30dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I tried changing lots of things, but I can't make it work.

Answer (score 2):

Would using a `LinearLayout` help? I'm not sure you need a `RelativeLayout` inside the `ScrollView` with just those buttons listed there.

Something like this (extra properties, ids, etc. need adding)...

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="@drawable/background_image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!-- Add buttons here... -->   

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This will scroll if it needs to, and not otherwise.

Comment: The problem is with LinearLayout is I cannot position views according to relativity right?

Comment: True, but the example above looks like they could be achieved with a LinearLayout. Perhaps a diagram of what you need (rather than screenshots) might clarify if that is not true.